# How can I set Vertical alignment bottom of the GridControl Image column using DevExpress with WPF?

Tags: devexpress, wpf-4.0, gridcontrol

I have a `GridControl` in `DeveExpress` with `WPF` and in that `GridControl` have a image column, my Problem is that how can I set image vertical alignment in bottom of the cell.

Please help me.

Any help appreciated!